# What is the difference between sophisticated and complicated

Tags: word-usage

All, I see these words are used many times literally or verbally. But I really don't know what is the difference between them.

Please review one of them which I got from a read.

> After an obligatory Hello World–caliber application, we construct a
>   more sophisticated application that implements a daytime server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sophisticated* implies a level of elegance and intelligent design that might not be present in something that is just *complicated*.  Also, a simple application could potentially be sophisticated if it had a lot of capacity despite its simplicity.